# Response time for an search with more than 1000 records is high

Tags: networking, performance-testing, database-performance

Response time for an search transaction with more than 1000 records has high response time for singapore client more than 4 to 5 time than USA client during 125 user load test.please suggest

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)

> **Elapsed time**. JMeter measures the elapsed time from just before sending the request to just after the last response has been received. JMeter does not include the time needed to render the response, nor does JMeter process any client code, for example Javascript.
>
> **Latency**. JMeter measures the latency from just before sending the request to just after the first response has been received. Thus the time includes all the processing needed to assemble the request as well as assembling the first part of the response, which in general will be longer than one byte. Protocol analysers (such as Wireshark) measure the time when bytes are actually sent/received over the interface. The JMeter time should be closer to that which is experienced by a browser or other application client.
>
> **Connect Time**. JMeter measures the time it took to establish the connection, including SSL handshake. Note that connect time is not automatically subtracted from latency. In case of connection error, the metric will be equal to the time it took to face the error, for example in case of Timeout, it should be equal to connection timeout.

So the formula is:

```
Response time = Connect Time + Latency + Actual Server Response time
```

So the reasons could be in:

1. Due to long distance from your load generators to Singapore you have worse results due to the time required for the network packets to travel back and forth [presumably due to high latency](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-analyze-results-load-test-using-blazemeter-0/)
2. Your Singapore instance is slower than the USA one due to i.e. worse hardware specifications, bandwidth, etc.